# javascript collapse table cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, html-table

I came up with the script to collapse a table

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rowVisible = true;
function toggleDisplay(tbl) {
   var tblRows = tbl.rows;
   for (i = 0; i < tblRows.length; i++) {
      if (tblRows[i].className != "headerRow") {
         tblRows[i].style.display = (rowVisible) ? "none" : "";
      }
   }
   rowVisible = !rowVisible;
}
</script>   


<div class="datagrid"><table id="thread_1">
<thead><tr class="headerRow">     

      <th WIDTH="100"><a href="#" onclick="toggleDisplay(document.getElementById('thread_1'))" STYLE="color: white">SLO</a></th>
```

It works fine but my problem is that I want to save the state when person leaves the website. I guess that the easiest way would be with cookie. I just haven't done something like this before. How can I do that?

Comment: Google HTML5 local storage. Cookies are for information that you need on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to support, let say IE7 you can use browser localStorage.

```js
// Our flag to determine if rows are hidden or not
var rowsVisible = localStorage.getItem('rowsVisible'),
    // Table handler
    table = document.getElementById('table');

// "rowHidden" not exists in localStorage yet
if (rowsVisible === null) {
    rowsVisible = true;
} else {
   // localStorage return string
    rowsVisible = rowsVisible === 'true' ? true : false;
}

toggleDisplay(table, rowsVisible ? '' : 'none');

document.getElementById('toggleBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    toggleDisplay(table);
}, false);

function toggleDisplay(tbl) {    
    var tblRows = table.rows,
        mode = rowsVisible ? '' : 'none';

    for (i = 0; i < tblRows.length; i++) {
        if (tblRows[i].className != "headerRow") {
            tblRows[i].style.display = mode;
        }
    }

    localStorage.setItem('rowsVisible', rowsVisible);
    rowsVisible = !rowsVisible;
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SXAZ4/36/

Comment: Doesn't work in my chrome or Firefox. Probably wouldn't work on mobile eater witch is kind of a big deal.

Comment: Also all new mobile browsers supports localStorage (iOS, Android, Blackberry, IE Mobile)

Comment: It works but only with one table. How can i make it work with 2 or more? http://jsfiddle.net/SXAZ4/68/

Comment: I wrapped this code to `tableExpander` function (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SXAZ4/71/). Just call `tableExpander('my-table-id')`

Comment: do you know an answer to my other similar question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222824/javascript-hide-row-in-table-local-storage